# How to get Inner Table data in a Table using selenium and c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I want to get count of the outer table. This is what i have tried till now..in HTML some of the parts I removed to reduce the length of the code.

```js
var reports =
  driver.FindElements(By.Id("Outer Table"));
var formss = new List < object > ();
foreach(var item in reports) {
  formss.Add(item);
}
```

```html
<div id="Outer Table" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <a class="VMIContentPanelHolder_TreeViewSiteSection_0">Fix Auto Leeds (TF 
    Smiths)</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <a class="VMIContentPanelHolder_TreeViewSiteSection_0">Fix Auto Bradford (TF 
    Smiths)</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You want count of rows inside table or something else?

Comment: The "Outer Table" is just a div.  Are you trying to count the elements in the div? Or the number of rows in the table in the div?  Need more clarity.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have just one table? This also enables things as column alignment.

Comment: I'm trying to count  #rows

Comment: inside the row the data will added withing another table **ex:-</table>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
    <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
        <a class="VMIContentPanelHolder_TreeViewSiteSection_0">Fix Auto Bradford (TF 
    Smiths)</a>
      </td>**

Comment: Please update your question with proper content and question what you want

Answer (score 0):

Sorted out the problem.
Here some importent articles>> 

1) http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/handle-dynamic-webtables-with-selenium-in-csharp/

2) http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/locators/

```
IWebElement TableDiv = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#VMIContentPanelHolder_TreeViewSiteSection"));
List<IWebElement> TableTagList = new List<IWebElement>(TableDiv.FindElements(By.TagName("table")));
var reportNameList = new List<string>();
foreach (var TableTag in TableTagList)
 {
  reportNameList.Add(TableTag.FindElement(By.TagName("a")).Text.ToString());
  }
properties.reportCount= reportNameList.Count();
var isListsDiffer = properties.reportList.Except(reportNameList).ToList();
properties.isReportsMatched = !isListsDiffer.Any();
properties.displayValues(properties);
```

thank you!!